# Node JS Chrome debugger with npm scripts

Tags: node.js, google-chrome

I'm using a third party npm library that operates on a file. For example:

```
 "replace": "jscodeshift -t transform.js ./index.js
```

There is a way to use Chrome debugger tools when adding a breakpoint to the `index.js` file?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a hidden question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) library?

You could have this script for example:

```
"dev": "nodemon --inspect src/index.js"
```

To open the console and see the server code, open the chrome console and click on the NodeJS icon:

[image]

It will stop any time a debugger is reached in the code.

Hope it helps!

Note: nodemon will also help you refreshing the server when any change is saved in the code.

Comment: I'm not running the script directly. The library runs it.

Comment: If you install nodemon and add `nodemon --inspect` to the script that runs the app it will run through nodemon :)